# How can I delete an external file in svn?

Tags: svn

I've set the svn:external property on a directory to pull an individual file from another section of the repo into that directory. so if I do a propget, I get

```
<my directory> - <externed file1> <repo url to file1>
```

Then I realized I picked the wrong file to extern. So I update the property and propget now returns

```
<my directory> - <externed file2> <repo url to file2>
```

But file1 is still in "my directory". So I try deleting file1. If I do an update, the file comes back. So then I tried deleting and committing. But I get an error stating svn cannot remove external files and to use propedit or propdel. Haven't I done this? The external property points to a different file now. I've also tried completely removing the external property from the directory, but it makes no difference.

How can I configure the property to no longer pull file1?

Comment: Did you commit the property change and *then* run `svn update`?

Comment: Yes, I did commit the property changes before before doing any updates.

Comment: svn update is supposed to remove the file for you. What version of SVN are you using? If all else fails, remove the entire directory and do svn update to get it back without the file.

Comment: Deleting the folder locally and rechecking it out worked. I guess there must have been something in that folder's .svn folder that was failing to sync with the server.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, under `svn 1.6.17`.  Also had to delete the directory.